# Setting up DHCP without ethernet

Tags: networking, dhcp, wired

I'm a noob to networking so bare with me. Since I want to learn how to network, I asked a friend about what I should start with. He told me I should learn home networking first such as DHCP and IPv4 networking and TCP/IP. Here's where the problem comes in:

The setup I have is this: 
1 modem, from my ISP which I'm guessing is a DHCP server but only leasing to itself(If thats possible). I took the ethernet cable from that into a switch which would give the switch internet. I then hooked my router up on a .1 subnet. What I'm trying to do is setup another subnet using my netbook as my DHCP server to hand out IP's to my computer which is also hooked into the same switch. If I'm correct, the subnet should just broadcast it to my computer which is hooked onto the same switch.

I don't know if it's a subnetting issue or if it's a gateway issue.

Edit: Im also using the command line if I needed to clear that up :P

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT6PS.jpg is what im trying to achieve, yet I cant get ethernet to work.

Bottom line: I cant connect to the internet to make everything else work. And i dont know why, I've done it with the best of my abilities.

It's been giving me a headache for 2 weeks now. I'm about to start my freshman year so I want to get it done with before school starts. Just tell me if you need me to give any information, or if i was just unclear. Thanks!

Edit: I had an idea, could i take the signal on eth0 and broadcast a signal to my computer using my wireless card?

Comment: Unless the modem is also a router and the router is configured as a simple access point it sounds like you are connecting the main computer on the WAN side of the router, which will isolate it from your LAN - are you sure that's what you intended? FWIW the RTNETLINK error sometimes occurs when you define more than one gateway with the same route metric - but without more detail about your setup it's hard to say for sure

Comment: Alright, I tried to make my setup a little clearer, if i need to Ill try to clarify even more.

Comment: Few things you could add to your questions. What kind of situation you are trying to achieve and why? Will you use that netbook only as a DHCP server or will you also use it for other things? Also add model names/number of the modem, router and switch.

Comment: When the router was connected to your modem. What IP adresses did it have? (both wan side and lan side)

Comment: If im correct, wan side of the router should be your public ip address right? If so its 97.83.142.193. For the lan side i believe the ip address is the one you use to log into to it. If im correct about that its 192.168.1.1